# How to create dynamic pages in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scenario, in this i have to develop pages containing various check box items.
User can select at least one option from that and submit the form.

[image]
from the above form, user can select multiple items and proceed to next step.
when user submit form, i have to show next page form data on the basis of user selection.

How can i do that in html and javascript?
or do i need to create this application using php?
(i dont know php)
Can you please suggest me reference links that can i follow to implement this.

Comment: @gideon Nice one, I was unaware of that site.

Comment: Is this a job that you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in javascript. On submit, check the checkbox selected and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using javascript. Here's an example form:

```
<form action="response.html" name="form1" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="param"></input>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

When you click submit it will redirect to the "action" page you specified, in my case to response.html
In that page the URL will be something like www.mydomain.com/response.html?param=myanswer

You can then pull them apart using javascript e.g.

```
<script>
   document.write(location.search);
</script>
```

You just have to split this up using methods like 'split', easy to google